# Warning: Cannot find callback list in XtAddCallback

Tags: c, ubuntu, callback, xorg, motif

I recently start using program Radware (1998) for nuclear data analysis based on C-language I have done following process one by one-
make all > make xm > make install
then in my Ubuntu (22.04.3 LTS) terminal run one program related to this program "xmgf3 "(motif version).
I got 100 lines of 'Warning: Cannot find callback list in XtAddCallback '
I am providing some block of xmgf3.c

```
void create_pdm(int pd, char *pdname, char *ButtonText, char ButtonMnemonic)
{
  /* subroutine to create pulldown menu panes and cascade buttons */

  pulldowns[pd] = XmCreatePulldownMenu(menubar, pdname, NULL, 0);
  XtSetArg(args[0], XmNsubMenuId, pulldowns[pd]);
  XtSetArg(args[1], XmNlabelString,
       XmStringCreate(ButtonText, XmSTRING_DEFAULT_CHARSET));
  XtSetArg(args[2], XmNmnemonic, ButtonMnemonic);
  menubarBtn[pd] = XmCreateCascadeButton(menubar, ButtonText, args, 3);
}

/* subroutine to create pulldown menu entries and buttons */
void create_pdm_sel(int pd, int pdb, char *pdbname, char *ButtonText,
            char ButtonMnemonic, char *ReturnText)
{
  /* subroutine to create pulldown menu entries and buttons */
  XtSetArg(args[0], XmNlabelString,
       XmStringCreate(ButtonText, XmSTRING_DEFAULT_CHARSET));
  XtSetArg(args[1], XmNmnemonic, ButtonMnemonic);
  pdmenuBtn[pd][pdb] = XmCreatePushButtonGadget(pulldowns[pd],
                        pdbname, args, 2);
  XtAddCallback(pdmenuBtn[pd][pdb], XmNactivateCallback,
        (XtCallbackProc) ButtonCB, (XtPointer) ReturnText);
}
```

also some block of Makefile are

```
     X_WIN_TOP  = /usr/include
     MOTIF_TOP  = /usr/include
#    MOTIF_TOP  = /usr/X11/LessTif/Motif1.2
             CC = cc
             FC = $(CC)
         CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -I$(MOTIF_TOP)/include -DHAVE_GNU_READLINE

         RANLIB = ranlib
             AR = ar rv
             RM = -rm -f
         RM_CMD = $(RM) *.o core* *[~%] *.trace

           LIBS = -lX11 -lm -lreadline -lncurses
     MOTIF_LIBS = -lXm -lMrm -lXt -lXext #-lXp
   STATIC_MOTIF = -lXm -lMrm -lXpm -lXt -lSM -lICE -lXext #-lXp
```

I don't know why program have been installed without giving any error but still motif based program not working and returning 'Warning: Cannot find callback list in XtAddCallback'